# jquery function not being properly executed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to implement an overlay on a page, however its not working as intended.

Use case:

- when user click search icon on a page, it displays an overlay
- when the overlay is displayed, user can click close button to remove the overlay

Problem:
When I refresh and view my js code in the browser, my overlay is already being visibly displayed, which shouldn't before I click the search icon, so am I not calling it properly?

I am calling both 'openOverlay' and 'closeOverlay' functions in the events() function in my Search.js which should trigger the function.

dev environment:

- node.js with webpack
- scripts.js: imports main css file and instantiate modules
- Search.js with my overlay code (imports jquery and exports default Search)

scripts.js

```
import "../css/styles.css"

// modules
import Search from "./modules/Search"

//instantiate new object using modules/classes
const search = new Search()

// Allow new JS and CSS to load in browser without a traditional page refresh
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

Search.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';


//alert("helo there");

function Search(){
    //describe/create object
    var openButton = $(".js-search-trigger");
    var closeButton = $(".s-overlay__close");
    var searchOverlay = $(".s-overlay");

    //events
    function events() {
        openButton.on("click", openOverlay);
        closeButton.on("click", closeOverlay);
    };
    events();
    
    //methods
    function openOverlay(){
        searchOverlay.addClass("s-overlay--active");
    };
    function closeOverlay(){
        searchOverlay.removeClass("s-overlay--active");
    };
}
export default Search;
```

html:

```
<div class="s-overlay s-overlay--active">
    <div class="s-overlay__top">
        <div class="s-container">
            <i class="s-overlay__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg>...</svg>
            </i>
            <input id="search-term" class="search-term" type="text" placeholder="What are looking for?">
            <i class="s-overlay__close" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg>...</svg>
            </i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.s-overlay { overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; z-index: 110; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.96); visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; transform: scale(1.09); transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, visibility 0.3s; box-sizing: border-box;}
.s-overlay--active { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
.s-overlay__top {  margin-top: 32px; position: relative; padding: 1em; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); }
.s-overlay__icon { line-height: 0; display: block; }
.s-overlay__close {margin-left: auto; line-height: 0; display: block; transition: all 0.3s;}
.s-overlay__close:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: As a first investigation step, I would add a `console.log('openOverlay')` and `console.log('closeOverlay')` to the methods, so that you exactly see when the methods are called. If they are not called on page load and you still see the overlay, I would assume an issue with your styling logic or the hot reloading. You could try to comment the last few lines of your `scripts.js`, so that you know if the hot reloading is causing issues here.

Comment: Alex I tested what you said and my overlay still persists and my css seems to be working like it should. However, when I call the openOverlay() and closeOverlay() functions independantly of events() it works, why would this be if I am calling events() to call both of those functions in it?

Comment: So you are sure that the 2 methods are definitely not already called on page load? Are you sure that this "visible overlay" state is not somehow a cached state from the hot module reloading? What about commenting the last few lines in the `scripts.js`, have you tried that?

Comment: Alex I commented out hot reload and the overlay still persists. when I do console.log on both methods each function name show up in the F12 console. event() doesn't seem to work if I am calling both methods in it, but if I add the openOverlay() and closeOverlay() functions independently the script works. Do I have to preventdefault first so it doesnt trigger it?

Comment: If you see both log statements already on page load without clicking anything, this means that you're click handlers are called immediately. Next I would try to extract the bindings out of the `events()` function. You could place them directly into the code like this: 

```openButton.on("click", () => searchOverlay.addClass("s-overlay--active"));
closeButton.on("click", () => searchOverlay.removeClass("s-overlay--active"));
```

Comment: that didnt seem to work, it just outputs hot reload enabled in F12, and nothing was changed.

Comment: try to break it down to a minimal example, for example a jsfiddle often helps here.

Comment: Alex I have tested in codepen here https://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/rNGRJwR however its doing the same thing, where the overlay persists. when you view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already assigned your active class to the DOM element on page load:

> `<div class="s-overlay s-overlay--active">`

Simply remove the class, then you should see your desired behavior.

```html
<div class="s-overlay">
```

Comment: Hm, it works in codepen, however in my node.js env, when I click the search icon on my page nothing happens...

Comment: When you inspect the DOM elements, is the active class added to the search-overlay element when you click?

Comment: Hey Alex, i removed the class from the element before, but I just commented out the hot module in the scripts.js and its working...

Comment: how can make the jquery run with hot module? why is it conflicting?

Comment: Please try the following. Inspect the DOM, find your `s-overlay` element. Now click the search icon. Do you find the active class now added to your element? Or is there a error in the console? It could be that the element the module generates a different scope, where you can't find the DOM elements.

Comment: Hey Alex, really weird, when I comment hot reload in scripts.js and inspect element while I click the icon, the active class is added to the element and the overlay works. however if I refresh the browser manually, and click the icon, it doesnt work. ??

Comment: Hard to say what's causing the issue here, but something is wrong with the hot reloading setup. Please refer to the Webpack docs if you can find more information on this.

Comment: Hey Alex,I finally found out why my js wasnt working: I had `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` at the top of my file instead of at the bottom...gosh, that sucked real hard.